# Change Row Alignment when TextStartsWith - Google Sheets scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following script is supposed to change the row horizontal alignment in a Google Sheet to 'right' if the value of column A in the row is 'A ' When I run the script i receive this Error:
*TypeError: SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule(...).whenTextStartsWith(...).setHorizontalAlignment is not a function
RowAlignment    @ Código.gs:9*

If for example I change the .setHorizontalAlignment to .setBackground (to change the color) it works..

Can anyone take a look at the below and provide some guidance?

Thanks!

```
function RowAlignment() {
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes cells in range A:A to align right if
  // they start with the text "A ".

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A:A");
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenTextStartsWith("A ")
    .setHorizontalAlignment('right')
    //    .setBackground("#FF0000")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build();
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason for your issue is due to that `setHorizontalAlignment(alignment)` is the method of Class Range. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sethorizontalalignmentalignment) This is not the method of Class ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder. By this, such an error occurs. This is the reason for your issue.

And, `setBackground(color)` is the method of Class ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder#setbackgroundcolor) By this, when you change `setHorizontalAlignment` to `setBackground`, no error occurs.

When you want to change the horizontal alignment of the cell value to "right" when the start text is `A` , how about using OnEdit trigger as follows?

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.value.indexOf("A ") != 0) return;
  e.range.setHorizontalAlignment('right');
}
```

When this script is used, when you put the sample text like `A sample` to a cell, the horizontal alignment of the value is set to "right".

**When you directly run this script, an error occcurs, please be careful this.**

#### References:

- [setHorizontalAlignment(alignment)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sethorizontalalignmentalignment)
- [setBackground(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder#setbackgroundcolor)
- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)